# WordPress standard text plugin

Tags: wordpress, plug-in

I'm looking for a WordPress plugin. I would like to save standard text for other authors on a WordPress blog and a button to insert the text inside a new post. I only find WordPress pugins that create shortcodes for these text blocks. But I would like to paste the text directly in the classic editor with a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to insert fixed text with some variables (fields) take a look at "Post Snippets".     I use it to create a standard header for some posts.  It allows me to merge text to variables entered in.  It is executed from a button on the text editor.